# Javascript function takes input into variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I'm creating a website and I'm wondering how it would possible that when a function occurs, the text inside an html input will automatically be converted into a variable. For example, I have a variable x that currently has no value. If I enter the word "hi" into an input and a button onclick function occurs, the variable x will now the value of "hi'. How can I achieve this?
My current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<form>
  
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Try:

```js
var x;
document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  x = document.querySelector('input').value;
  console.log("x is: "+x);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input value="Submit" type="button">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple with both jQuery and Vanilla

`element.value` for Vanilla and `$(element).val()` for jQuery.

With an onclick event:

#### Vanilla

```js
function getValue() {
  var value = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
<button id="submit" onclick="getValue()">Submit</button>
```

#### jQuery

```js
function getValue() {
  var result = $("#lname").val();
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
<button id="submit" onclick="getValue()">Submit</button>
```

##### With event listeners

#### Vanilla

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
  var value = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

#### jQuery

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var value = $("#lname").val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Notice I removed the form. Otherwise, when you click submit you will be redirected to another page.